# Loop through files in directory and place in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ftp

I am trying to access csv files in an ftp server called Folder 1.
After accessing the folder1 I am trying to loop through all csv's and place them in a dataframe. My goal is to append all the csv's together into one dataframe.
Currently this is what I see when running the following code:

```
import ftplib
with ftplib.FTP('ftpserver.com') as ftp:
    ftp.login('username','Pw')
    ftp.cwd("/folder1")
```

Results in:

```
12-02-21  05:06AM       <DIR>          Data
12-02-21  11:32AM       <DIR>          MoreData
12-04-21  13:03PM              13145 first.csv
12-04-21  01:01AM              13146 second.csv
```

I am having trouble looping through this folder- "folder1" and placing all the csv's into a dataframe.
The following is the code I am currently stuck on, currently unable to even open up one file in the ftp server with a known file name:

```
import ftplib
with ftplib.FTP('ftpserver.com') as ftp:
    ftp.login('username','Pw')
    ftp.cwd("/folder1")
    with open("first.csv", "r") as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
```